# UWP: What is the DevToolsUser Password?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, remote-debugging

I am trying to deploy an UWP application to a Surface Pro 4 device(remote machine) and I get a strange error(i should mention i have installed Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger on the target machine).

Does anyone know what is the password for this user?

[image]

Comment: If you use Windows Authentication it should be your login credentials. I normally just disable auth all together since it's easier.

Comment: it seems to be working now...but I got another error. Maybe that's another question...